# Python 2.7 conversion to 3

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found a code snippet online, that would be able to display sensor readings from an android phone, but I need this to run on Python 3. And I have no idea how to fix it:

```
# -------------------------------------------------------
import socket, traceback, string
from sys import stderr

host = ''
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind((host, port))

# print one blank line
print 

while 1:
    try:
        message, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
#        print message

# split records using comma as delimiter (data are streamed in CSV format)
        data = message.split( "," )

# convert to flaot for plotting purposes
        t = data[0]
        sensorID = int(data[1])
        if sensorID==3:     # sensor ID for the eccelerometer
            ax, ay, az = data[2], data[3], data[4]
# SAVE TO FILE
#            print >> open("prova.txt","a"), t, ax, ay, az
#            print t, ax, ay, az
# FLUSH TO STERR
            stderr.write("\r t = %s s |  (ax,ay,az) = (%s,%s,%s) m/s^2" % (t, ax, ay, az) )
            stderr.flush()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
# -------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desktop\androidSensor123.py", line 21, in <module>
    data = message.split( "," )
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Have you used the `2to3` script?

Comment: Try `data = message.split(b"," )`. Though that may lead to other problems further down the road.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham [`recvfrom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) returns a bytes object, so `message` will indeed by `bytes` and can't be split by a `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're trying to split `bytes` object

convert it back to a string like this, by decoding the bytes back to a string

```
data = data.decode() # you can also specify the encoding of the string if it's not unicode
data = message.split(",")
```

this is a demonstration of what is going on

```
>>> a = b'hello,world'
>>> a.split(',')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>> a = a.decode()
>>> a.split(',')
['hello', 'world']
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip: but in this format:    data = message.decode(), data = data.split( "," )